# Show that $(I − P)^2 = I − P$ if $P=P^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents, projection-matrices

> Let $P $ be an $n \times n$ matrix and $I$ be the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Show that $$ (I − P)^2 = I − P $$ is valid if $P = P^2$.

I did the following.

$$(I - P)^2 = I^2 - IP - PI + P^2 = I - P$$

where $I^2 = I $ because it is the identity matrix. Is this enough to show or did I miss something?

Comment: Perfect........

Comment: Note that $(A-B)^2=A^2-2AB+B^2$ holds only if $A$ and $B$ commute. Either you explain the first step by mentioning that $I$ and $P$ commute, or you should write $(I-P)^2=I^2-IP-PI+P^2$.

Comment: yeah u are right I did forget that .........

Comment: You should specify you don't work on a field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: @Bernard Why? In which step is this condition needed?

Comment: what exactly does that mean?

Comment: It means that $2\cdot 1_K=0_K$ ($K$ is the base field. This is the case with  e.g. $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$).

Comment: @Bernard: That would be relevant if the OP was trying to prove an equivalence, but that doesn't seem to be the case (in any of the versions of this post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speculate about what "sth" means (I thought it indicated the $s$th element of some sequence, at first, for some natural number $s$) but I'd say you are close!

I'd be a bit more explicit at this stage.

\begin{eqnarray}(I-P)^2 &=& I^2-IP-PI+P^2\\ &=& I-P-P+P^2\\ &=& I-P-P+P\\ &=& I-P\end{eqnarray}

Can you justify *each* equality?

Comment: yes I can .........